# tezos-client - unknown protocol

Tags: tezos-client

I have installed all 8.2 binaries for Ubuntu. The tezos-node is currently synching.

```
curl http://localhost:8732/version {"version":{"major":8,"minor":2,"additional_info":"release"},"network_version":{"chain_name":"TEZOS_MAINNET","distributed_db_version":1,"p2p_version":1},"commit_info":{"commit_hash":"6102c808a21b32e732ab9bb1825761cd056f3e86","commit_date":"2021-02-10 22:57:06 +0100"}}

curl http://localhost:8732/monitor/bootstrapped
{"block":"BLHH1Ugrv8niE7h73iEEwTqYY7EHJACVd5jaV6eLD4TngxD4dTb","timestamp":"2019-02-14T16:22:43Z"}
{"block":"BMKzAY9i8uDG4szbgqfAjkA4dCs3Jtq8mEBCchwJSvSv9hLiU7e","timestamp":"2019-02-14T16:23:43Z"}
{"block":"BLABfJJrG82Ara8XKQssaBNbAiLrVz6MnVKacTgijD6NNgkPjX4","timestamp":"2019-02-14T16:24:43Z"}
```

I have an issue with the tezos-client anything i try gives the unknown protocol error

```
tezos-client man -v 3
Disclaimer:
  The  Tezos  network  is  a  new  blockchain technology.
  Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
  with usage of the Tezos network.  Users should do their
  own  research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
  platform for their needs and should apply judgement and
  care in their network interactions.

Fatal error: unknown protocol version.
```

some help?

Comment: I can use it like this: tezos-client -p PtEdo2ZkT

Comment: Warning:
  The protocol provided via `--protocol` (PtEdo2ZkT9oK)
  is not the one retrieved from the node (PsddFKi32cMJ).

Comment: so I just need for the node to get sync? that's it?

Answer (score 1):

One issue might be that you are using an outdated version of `tezos-client`.
Mainnet updates the protocol level every so often and you will need to update `tezos-client` accordingly.

Downloaded the most recent version here:
[github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases)

You can also track the protocol versions here:
[tzkt.io/protocols](https://tzkt.io/protocols)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is going to help you, but it has worked for me:

```
brew tap serokell/tezos-packaging https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging.git
brew unlink tezos-client
brew link tezos-client
```